# Bubble sort code doesn't work, returns no output. Please assists

Tags: python-2.7

## Created 2 functions calling bubblesort in second function.

```
  def bubblesort(s):
       for i in range(len(s)-1):
                      for j in i:
                           if x[j]>s[j+1]:
                           p=s[j+1]
                           s[j+1]=s[j]
                           s[j]=p
  return s
  def main():
      x=[]
      z=1
      while z<=4:
          y =  int(raw_input("enter your numbers: ")) 
          z +=1
          x.append(y)   
          print "Your input: " + x
          print bubblesort(x)

  raw_input ("press<enter>")
```

its not printing the sorted output

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: python bubble.py 
enter your numbers: 34
Your input: [34]
[34]
enter your numbers: 56
Your input: [34, 56]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bubble.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "bubble.py", line 17, in main
    print bubblesort(x)
  File "bubble.py", line 3, in bubblesort
    for j in i:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
Shandeeps-MacBook-Pro:pythonfile shandeepkm$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling your main() function anywhere.

Try adding `main()` before the final `raw_input` line.

Also, your whitespace seems to be a bit messed up from where you copied to stack overflow. For example, the `return s` line should be inside the `bubblesort` function.

Another mistake is that, for the line `print "Your input: " + x`, you need to convert `x` to a string. So `str(x)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, I did the changes but now it doesn't give the out.

Comment: python bubble.py 
enter your numbers: 34
Your input: [34]
[34]
enter your numbers: 56
Your input: [34, 56]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bubble.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "bubble.py", line 17, in main
    print bubblesort(x)
  File "bubble.py", line 3, in bubblesort
    for j in i:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: That error is since you're trying to iterate through `i` which is a number.

Comment: So the final code, it worked:def bubblesort(s):
    p = 0
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
           for j in range(len(s)-1):
              if s[j]>s[j+1]:
                  p=s[j+1]
                  s[j+1]=s[j]
                  s[j]=p
    return s
def main():
      x=[]
      z=1
      while z<=6:
            y =  int(raw_input("enter your numbers: "))
            z +=1
            x.append(y)
            print "Your input: " + str(x)
            print bubblesort(x)

main()
raw_input ("pres<enter>")

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked:

```
def bubblesort(s):
     p = 0
     for i in range(len(s)-1):
          for j in range(len(s)-1):
             if s[j]>s[j+1]:
               p=s[j+1]
               s[j+1]=s[j]
               s[j]=p
     return s
def main():
  x=[]
  z=1
  while z<=6:
        y =  int(raw_input("enter your numbers: "))
        z +=1
        x.append(y)
        print "Your input: " + str(x)
        print bubblesort(x)

main()
raw_input ("pres<enter>")
```

But I need to know why I cant iterate an int type 'i'. When the i = range(len(s)-1) in the line 'for j in i' instead of 'for j in range(len(s)-1)'.

Comment: `for i in range(10)` iterates through `i=0`, `i=1`, ... `i=9`. `for j in i` doesn't make sense because `i` is not a list, but merely a number.

Comment: Oh! Okay, that makes perfect sense. Thank you.